# How to centralize title that is in navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to center the name `NAMETOOL` which is in `navbarPage`. See in the attached image that the title is well to the left. I would therefore like to leave it more in the center.

Code executable below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="NAMETOOL", collapsible = TRUE, selected = "HOME", 
                        
                        
                        tags$head(
                
                          tags$style(HTML("
                          div.container-fluid { padding:0; } /* Remove padding here */
                           .navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }"
                          ))
                        ),
                        
                        tabPanel("HOME",
                                 icon = icon("home"),
                                 div(
                                   style =
                                     "height: 315x; background-color: rgba(0,0,0); width: 100%; position: relative; right:0;padding:0;",
                                   
                                   tags$iframe(width="853", height="480", src="", 
                   
                                               frameborder="0", allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
                                               picture-in-picture", allowfullscreen=NA)
                                 ),style="text-align:center",
                                 
                                   div(
                                     style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
                                     
                                     h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
                                        style="text-align:center; color: white;"),
                                     br(),
                                     tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}"))))





server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Maybe try adding spaces befode the name to do a quick fix.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Try adding the title with something like `title = div("       Title")` and add spaces then see if that works.

Comment: Thanks @Ed_Gravy! I tried but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      span.navbar-brand {margin: auto !important;}
      div.container-fluid { padding: 0; } /* Remove padding here */
      .navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }"))
  ),
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
    title = "NAMETOOL", collapsible = TRUE, selected = "HOME",
    tabPanel("HOME",
      icon = icon("home"),
      div(
        style =
          "height: 315x; background-color: rgba(0,0,0); width: 100%; position: relative; right:0;padding:0;",
        tags$iframe(
          width = "853", height = "480", src = "", frameborder = "0", 
          allow = "accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture", 
          allowfullscreen = NA
        )
      ), 
      style = "text-align:center",
      div(
        style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
        h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
          style = "text-align:center; color: white;"
        ),
        br(),
        tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```